# C# Loading screen threading loading and animation

Tags: c#, multithreading, xna, loading

I'm making a loading screen for a game in c#. Do I need to create a thread for drawing the spinning animation as well as a thread for loading the level?

I'm a bit confused as to how it works. I've spent quite a few hours messing with it to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of anything that XNA may provide for you, anytime you require doing multiple units of work at once, multiple threads are usually required - and almost certainly if you want to benefit from multiple CPUs.  Depending upon exactly what you're looking to do, you're already in one thread (for your main method / program execution) - so you don't likely need to create 2 additional threads - but just one additional for either the loading of your level, or for the animation.

Alternatively, as was probably more common-place in older development when developers weren't concerned with multi-core CPUs, etc., you could use tricks such as doing both the level loading and the animation in the same thread - but at the expense of additional complexity for combining both concerns into the same unit of processing.  (In every x # of lines of processing for loading the level, add code to update the loading animation.)  However, given today's technology, you are almost certainly better off using multiple threads for this.

Answer (score 0):

Loading takes time because it makes long calculations and long calculations are usually done in a different thread so that the program woun't freeze.

So the answer is yes.